# Как узнать версию android studio в которой был сделан проект

Tags: android-studio

Скачал проект с гитхаба. Как узнать в какой версии Android Studio он был сделан ?

Comment: А если он был сделан в трех версиях АС, то что вы хотите узнать? Версия АС ни на что не влияет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При создании проекта не имеет разницы в какой версии `Android Studio` он был создан. Другое дело это например версия `gradle`. Если будут конфликтовать версии, то вам будет предложено обновить его к более новой версии. Чаще всего в библиотеках которые есть на гитхабе указываются зависимости которые необходимы для работы с библиотекой и все. Версия `Ide` не играет никакой роли.